# Objects snap to custum grid on fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am building an app where I need the objects snap to a grid on mouseMove but I don't need a regular grid but a custumized one. I found this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/) and tried to place my own grid but objects do not snap to it. What I need is the center of the objects to snap to the cross formed by two grid lines.

This is my code:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var grid = 20;

// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (canvas.height / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 260.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 309.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 353.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 391.25,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 419.25,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 435.25,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 216.5,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 179,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 151,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 135,122.82188 0,349.31925 ', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));

  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,147.25 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,161.25 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,188 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,224.75 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,269.75 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,326.05147 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,370.83102 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,407.75 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,434.25 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,448.5 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  fill: '#faa',
  originX: 'center',  originY: 'center',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

If someone able to help it will be welcomed.

After analyzing this again I have found that the svg is snapping to a grid maybe given in this `var` `var grid = 20;` but not to the grid I've created using `canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,147.25 348.63852,0', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));`. This is likely the culprit though I am not sure.

Comment: You need to create your grid spaced the amount you have in your x and y axis you are using each `canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 260.75,122.82188 0,349.31925'`. So you define the start of the canvas on the page, x axis 110, then add each spacing to the x axis in an object for coords, repeat this for y axis and then build your grid variable with this spacing. Set your eventlistener for mouse move to iterate over that object, inserting the top/left => y/x axis from your object with each iteration. Theoretically, this should snap the mouse movements to the grid you've created.

Comment: For example, your canvas starts at x axis of 111, the next x line you create is @ 135, this is a spacing of 24, this would be the first value in your spacing obj for coords x. Next would be the subtraction of your next x axis line, 151 -135 = 16, 179 - 151 = 28. So your obj would look like `spacingObj = [{ start{ x: 111, y: 100 }, coords : { x : [ 24, 16, 28, etc... ] }, y : [24.5, 14.5, 26,5, etc...] } ]` keep adding each one until you have the last line mapped, both in x and y axis. Then you use the start and x/y coords to create your grid and reference in your mousemove eventListener.

Comment: Lastly you would have to initially snap your circle object to one of these mapped lines x and y connection points. You would likely have to check direction of mouse move axis for this as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I perfectly understood the logic behind your suggestion and I will give it a try, maybe I get stuck again as my Js skills are very limited but I will try. Thanks very much!

Comment: Then, if I create the  spacingObj  I won't need the paths to be drawn anymore? Or am i wrong and will need to keep them too?

Comment: No you use the obj to draw the grid dynamically. Two for loops embedded in your create grid loop, each referencing the x and y coords in your obj.

Comment: Now it is done and working properly. Thanks a lot. Could you please take a look at this two questions, one is recent and the other is two months old. both are related with the same project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950540/fabric-js-svg-elements-to-pop-up-on-click-to-be-edited-and-then-return-to-its-pr  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818730/auto-generating-svg-objects-in-fabric-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the `var grid = 20` is exactly what is causing your issue as you have a grid that is not spaced the same. You have statically created your grid, however using an object that defined the starting points and spacing would be more dynamic and allow you to use that same object to snap your event to the dynamically created grid points.

I was able to do this using an *array of objects* for the *grid spacing* and instantiating both a **start** and **coords** object with an array for both ***x*** and ***y*** placing the lines into the coords object under each coord key.

The ***coords*** object is actually the space between each line from the starting position. The ***start*** object is the start position of the edge of the lines being drawn both in ***x*** and ***y*** axis.

We will use these objects to dynamically create the grid and a ***points*** object to reference later for snapping the mouse move to the grid.

Define the starting point using `gridSpacing[0]['start']['x']` and `gridSpacing[0]['start']['y']`. Then two arrays to hold the values for the dynamically created *x axis lines* and *y axis lines* - `xArr` and `yArr`.

We then create a nested for loop, looping over both ***xArr*** and ***yArr*** to create a ***points*** object.

Two more for loops to dynamically create the grid using the **xArr*** and ***yArr*** arrays.

Lastly the snapping portion within the `object:moving` event. Instantiate an axis object that will hold `the event.target.left` and `event.target.top` properties as key/value pairs. We use this to iterate over the ***points*** object and use conditionals to check the position of the mouse move event in relation to the points objects key/values => ***keys*** for the **x axis** and ***values*** for the **y axis**.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});

// insantiate object for starting and coordinates of spacing
const gridSpacing = [{
  start: {
    x: 111,
    y: 123.25
  },
  coords: {
    x: [24, 16, 28, 37.5, 44.25, 49, 44, 37.5, 28, 16],
    y: [24, 16, 28, 37.5, 44.25, 49, 44, 37.5, 28, 16]
  }
}]

// create grid

// define the starting coords
let xCoords = gridSpacing[0]['start']['x'];
let yCoords = gridSpacing[0]['start']['y'];

// instantiate x axis and y axis arrays
let xArr = []
let yArr = []

// fill xArr with values using gridSpacing object
for (let x = 0; x < gridSpacing[0].coords['x'].length; x++) {
  let spacing = gridSpacing[0].coords['x'][x]
  xArr.push(xCoords += spacing)
}
// fill yArr with values using gridSpacing object
for (let y = 0; y < gridSpacing[0].coords['y'].length; y++) {
  let spacing = gridSpacing[0].coords['y'][y]
  yArr.push(yCoords += spacing)
}
// instantiate points obj using xArr and yArr for in loops
const points = []
for (let i in xArr) {
  for (let y in yArr) {
    points.push({
      [xArr[i]]: yArr[y]
    })
  }
}

/* EDIT: This is the section that draws the grid lines. No need for it as you are using the points object and xArr and yArr to make your mouse snap to the spacing. 

// create and draw x axis grid dynamically using xArr
for (let x = 0; x < xArr.length; x++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path(`m ${xArr[x]},122.82188 0,349.31925`, {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
}
// create and draw y axis grid dynamically using yArr
for (let y = 0; y < gridSpacing[0].coords['y'].length; y++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path(`m 110.91682,${yArr[y]} 348.63852,0`, {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
}
*/

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  fill: '#faa',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  left: xArr[5],
  top: yArr[5],
  radius: 60,
  fill: '#9f9',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(event) {
  // create objbect that will hold current mouse move events x and y
  let axis = {
    [event.target.left]: event.target.top
  }  
  let x, y = '';
  // iterate over our points and check event.target values
  points.forEach((point, i) => {
    // conditional to check x axis boundaries and point variations
    // left
    if (parseInt(Object.keys(axis)) < xArr[1] - xArr[1] * .1 || parseInt(Object.keys(axis)) < xArr[0]) {
      x = xArr[0]
    // right
    }else if (parseInt(Object.keys(axis)) > xArr[xArr.length - 1]) {
      x = xArr[xArr.length - 1]
    // boundaries
    }else if (Object.keys(axis) < Object.keys(points[i]) && Object.keys(axis) > Object.keys(points[i - 1]) && Object.keys(axis) > xArr[0]) {
      x = Object.keys(points[i])
    }
    
    // conditional to check y axis boundaries and point variations
    // up
    if (parseInt(Object.values(axis)) < yArr[1] - yArr[1] * .1 || parseInt(Object.values(axis)) < yArr[0]) {
      y = yArr[0]
    // down
    }else if (parseInt(Object.values(axis)) > yArr[yArr.length - 1]) {
      y = yArr[yArr.length - 1]
      // boundaries
    }else if (Object.values(axis) < Object.values(points[i]) && Object.values(axis) > Object.values(points[i - 1]) && Object.values(axis) > xArr[0]) {
      y = Object.values(points[i])
    }
  }) 
  // set event.target left and top properties
  event.target.set({
    left: parseInt(x),
    top: parseInt(y)
  })
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, that's just what i needed. you even gave me time to try it out! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a huge step becasue this made me suffer for a month. Now I can move forward on this project. But I would ask you, if there's something else with this fabric.js that may be stopping me again can I count on you for a little help?

Comment: One question. may I use the grid without drawing it? I mean, if I can set something like 'opacity:0' or even get rid of the drawing part? I really used the grid to show the crossing points in wich I needed the object to snap to but there will be other static objects in this cross points. Should I avoid visually drawing the grid, or even, not drawing it at all?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS You do not need to draw the lines no. You can simply comment out that part which are the two for loops using the x and y axis arrays xArr and yArr. I have updated the with those two loops commented out.

Comment: Right now I'm refactoring into my real scenario. Wish me luck!

Comment: Hi, dale landry, I managed to calculate the spacing between lines for both axis but I can not make them be positioned in the right place. The starting point of x and y axis are troubling me. Are they set at the first intersection from top left? Or are they set, x at the starting point where the first horizontal line is being draw and y at the starting point where the first vertical line is being draw?

Comment: The starting point is the side of where the lines start. SO if you look at the object gridSpacing... The object `start` is the starting point and the object `coords` are the spacing. Everything is built off that array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

##### Firstly

I hope your `html` structure is okay at your local code.

##### Secondly

You are running a for loop that is drawing the same line 30 times actually. You can do it in a function and run only once:

```
function createGrid() {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 260.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
    canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 309.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
...
}
//then run it once:
createGrid();
```

Since your grid is not spaced in an irregular way, you don't need this:

```
var grid = 20;
```

My approach would be retrieving all the horizontal and vertical snapping points and find the closest x and y axis to do the snap.

Something like this:

```
const horizontalSnappingPoints = options.target.canvas._objects
  .filter((el, index) => options.target.canvas._objects
    .some((sameTopEl, sameTopElIndex) => sameTopEl.top === el.top && sameTopElIndex !== index)).map(item => item.left);
```

Same for the vertical one and then find the closest point according to each direction while setting the left/top properties.

```
left: horizontalSnappingPoints.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - options.target.left) < Math.abs(prev - options.target.left) ? curr : prev);
```

##### Snippet

Here is the final snippet:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});

// create grid
function createGrid() {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 260.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 309.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 353.75,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 391.25,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 419.25,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 435.25,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 216.5,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 179,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 151,122.82188 0,349.31925', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 135,122.82188 0,349.31925 ', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));

  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,147.25 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,161.25 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,188 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,224.75 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,269.75 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,326.05147 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,370.83102 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,407.75 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,434.25 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Path('m 110.91682,448.5 348.63852,0', {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
}

// call this to actually create grids
createGrid();

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  fill: '#faa',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  left: 300,
  top: 300,
  radius: 60,
  fill: '#9f9',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  let horizontalSnappingPoints = options.target.canvas._objects.filter(item => item.path)
  horizontalSnappingPoints = horizontalSnappingPoints.filter((el, index) => horizontalSnappingPoints
    .some((sameTopEl, sameTopElIndex) => sameTopEl.top === el.top && sameTopElIndex !== index)).map(item => item.left);

  let verticalSnappingPoints = options.target.canvas._objects.filter(item => item.path)
  verticalSnappingPoints = verticalSnappingPoints.filter((el, index) => verticalSnappingPoints
    .some((sameLeftEl, sameLeftElIndex) => sameLeftEl.left === el.left && sameLeftElIndex !== index)).map(item => item.top)

  options.target.set({
    left: horizontalSnappingPoints.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr - options.target.left) < Math.abs(prev - options.target.left) ? curr : prev);
    }),
    top: verticalSnappingPoints.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr - options.target.top) < Math.abs(prev - options.target.top) ? curr : prev);
    }),
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Towkir, Thank you very much for your answer, it also works very fine and I apprecciate the effort, but I going to accept the **dale landry's** answer as he came first and ansewred first. But anyway I will up vote your answer as it also works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries @SIMBIOSIS, I had fun solving it as it was an interesting problem. dale's solution is pretty elegant, specially the grid generation and saving the coordinates. I upvoted his answer even before posting my one and he deserves the reward ;)

Comment: Anyway I'm pretty sure I will be stuck again on this project as it goes on and I've never used fabric.js before and my javascript skills are pretty limited too. Maybe you'll help to solve my next issue.

Comment: Hi, Towkir, I've been testing your solution and it happens that I can not move objects beyond the last vertical grid line on the right side and beyond the first horizontal line on the top. My question is, was this intentional or it just happened? No matter if your answer is yes or no, can it be possible to extend this effect to restrict dragging beyond the first vertical grid line on the left?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS As you asked in your question, they should snap to the coordinates where x and y axis crosses each other. if they can move beyond those snapping points, where should they snap ? or do you want them to move freely out of the grid lines and when they come close to the snapping coordinates, then snap them ?

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate well my question in the above comment. Your solution is working as I requested, like a charm. I just wanted to know if there is a way to avoid the objects to move out of the grid on the left side just like they are constraint on the upper and right sides. I know that in the example I provided the pink square is located at the top left of the canvas, my mistake, because in my real project the objects to be moved are located on the bottom side. Just asking if there is a way to restrict them to go beyond the grid on the left side too.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your comment. About that the code had a bug, it wasn't intentional. I've fixed it now, previously the way I was calculating the grid lines, I thought I was eliminating the other two elements, box and rect. But due to the bug, they were adding up in the path calculation. I updated the section in `canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {` you can check now