# Auto-generating svg objects in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, fabricjs

I am building an app using **`fabric.js`** to relay on some functionalities. In my `canvas` I have created a set of objects which will be used as menu items to be dragged and placed, by the user, somewhere else within the canvas. Everything is working ok, but I need help in a couple of things.

After playing around and investigating a lot I have come with this simple solution. `canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) { my objects });` and it's working fine but there are two drawbacks. Run the snippet and you will realize. I'll explain later.

This is my code:

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {

var prthss = new fabric.Path('m 37.066323,664.72823 c -0.526572,-7.80009 -0.530124,-15.64425 -0.0136,-23.48118 5.487368,-4.37172 13.310902,-4.34082 18.754907,0.0798 -0.533656,7.62909 -0.579648,15.59958 0.03127,23.20784 -5.375259,4.48954 -13.24684,4.55212 -18.772561,0.19357 z');
prthss.set({fill: '#fff', stroke: '#1a1a1a', strokeWidth: 2, opacity: 1, left:130, top:110, lockScalingX: true, lockScalingY: true, originX: 'center',  originY: 'center' });
prthss.set('selectable', true);
prthss.setControlsVisibility({ mt: false, mb: false, ml: false, mr: false, bl: false, br: false, tl: false, tr: false, mtr: true, });
canvas.add(prthss);

var tpr = new fabric.Path('m 313.13828,618.74455 c 2.11345,1.08854 2.18323,3.22159 2.1986,5.06456 m -23.10338,-9.61297 7.80969,0 -4.00165,0 0.0394,9.61297 m 5.78092,0 0.0394,-9.61297 2.83155,0 c 3.28759,0 3.40318,4.60019 0,4.60019 l -2.91027,0 m 8.34298,5.01278 0.0394,-9.61297 2.83154,0 c 3.2876,0 3.40319,4.60019 0,4.60019 l -2.91026,0 m 9.56121,-0.23614 c 0,8.35908 -6.77638,15.13546 -15.13545,15.13546 -8.35909,0 -15.13547,-6.77637 -15.13547,-15.13546 0,-8.35908 6.77638,-15.13544 15.13547,-15.13544 8.35907,0 15.13545,6.77638 15.13545,15.13544 z');
tpr.set({fill: '#fff', stroke: '#1a1a1a', strokeWidth: 2, opacity: 1, left:100, top:110, lockRotation: 'true', originX: 'center',  originY: 'center' });
canvas.add(tpr);
});
```

```css
.controls {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h3>Menu with autogenerative items </h3>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

As I said it's working fine but:

DRAWBACKS:

1. The objects serving as menu items are blurred and distorted on the edges. I have notice, seeing it here and also in my own proyect, that this distortion have a similar pattern. See this picture and compare. [image]. I have tried setting a thicker border and also setting some opacity levels but nothing really helped.
2. In my own proyect, where there are 19 of this menu items and almos 50 other static objects on the canvas, the whole code runs pretty slower after applying this solution. I have tried applying the solution just to few of the items but the sluggishness doe not go away.

Does anybody knows why these both drawbacks happen?

Does anybody can solve this as the first makes the whole thing look ugly and the second makes it look pretty sluggish?

What did I did wrong?

Comment: JQuery does not work with svg but the rest of the code I'm using does, so all the code I have written to deal with fabric is written also for jQuery. I really don't understand why but if I remove the jQuery link the fabric stuff does not load at all.

Comment: I have ckecked it out and realized that the whole jQuery stuff within the fabric script could be removed as unnecessary, so I did it and it's working fine. Then the jQuery stuff is not longer a requirement in this question. Thanks Robert Longson for the warning!

Comment: I have updated the question as I have found a working solution but this brought two drawbacks into scenes.